# Changing Positions of the Chart When Creating Multiple Charts Automatically via Vbasic in Excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I am creating a new chart for each row of data in an Excel spreadsheet.  I have the Vbasic working properly, but I want to change the position of the chart on the sheet that is added for each row.

Below is my code, what do I need to do to change the position of the chart on the page automatically?  Ideally, I would like it to be in the upper left hand corner of each sheet.

```
Sub DrawCharts()
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim NewWs As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim CurrRow As Long

Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = Ws.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
For CurrRow = 2 To LastRow
    Set NewWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    NewWs.Name = Ws.Range("A" & CurrRow).Value
    Set cht = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
    With cht
        .ChartType = xl3DColumnClustered
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & Ws.Name & "!R" & CurrRow & "C3:R" & CurrRow & "C8"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=" & Ws.Name & "!R" & CurrRow & "C2"
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "Sheet1!R1C3:R1C8"
    .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.2
        .SetElement (msoElementDataLabelShow)
        .SetElement (msoElementLegendNone)
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=NewWs.Name
    End With
Next CurrRow
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After

> .Location

put in this line:

```
.Left = 0
.Top = 0
```

you might also try

```
.PlotArea.Left = 0
.PlotArea.Top = 0
```

It might give a slightly different placement.